# iMovie Update Questions

Tags: macos, imovie

Lately I've been working on videography, but I've been using iMovie on my MacBook Pro, and its about 8 years old, and I know for sure there's an update for the iMovie, but when I go to app store it says theres no updates?

Comment: Could you provide more details like OS version and iMovie version ?

Comment: I went to the app store and it said there was another app for imovie and i tried downloading it, but it said I needed to download OS X version 10.11.2 but my computer doesn't say I have anymore updates for my Os

Comment: Which OS are you running now ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not provided OS version and from the age of your laptop, I consider that you are not running the required OS for the latest iMovie version. The latest iMovie version is v10.1.5 and the minimum system requirement is OS X 10.11.2 or later. When you open iMovie, it may inform you that there is a update on the MAS, but it also asks you to update the OS.